# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Works sometimes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql

I have a couple of versions of a project that run with mysql2. I have a version on my desktop which works fine. However i uploaded it on svn and that also works. After a colleague of mine added some css files now it stopped working. It gives the above error. Previously i had problems with passwords etc which gave the same error which i resolved. Now the version on my desktop alone works however the source controlled version is not working. Any idea where i should check for any problems? I also added a mysql dump file into the project folder.

Comment: I fail to see how CSS files could affect a mysql connection...

Comment: ME TOO! -- Thats why im stuck :)

Comment: It's entirely possible that that colleague changed more than CSS files (inadvertently). Have you looked at his commit to see exactly what changed? Have you tried rolling back to a known working commit?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the password you are trying to use to connect to the server is wrong, or you are attempting to use a password to connect to an account with no password (which, given that it's the root account, I sincerely hope not). Check your database.yaml files to verify the correct password is being used. Check any migrations you've written as well.

Also, you should **never** use the `root` account to connect to your server from an application. Create a user with limited privileges and use that account. For example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO myapp@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Ideally you would only grant the privileges necessary to use the database, but granting all privileges for just one database is common. The key is that a compromised app would only be able to do damage to one specific database rather than any database on the server.

Comment: The passwords are correct on the config file and the app im trying to connect to. HOwever like you said I will try adding a user and using it this way.